# Datatables search not working with columns

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a datatables which contains 4 columns. In these columns will display image filename with image preview.
I used to search by filename. it's working it but there is a problem with search filter which is not working correctly
the scenario, single row with contains 4 columns only. i want to search by particular file name. i tried it but not working it. can you please help on this

```
<table id="gallery" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Image 1</th>
            <th>Image 2</th>
            <th>Image 3</th>
            <th>Image 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
             <th><input type="radio" id="pickimg0" value="FileName.png"><img style="height: 80px;" class="item lazy" src="FileName.png">FileName.png</th>
            <th><input type="radio" id="pickimg1" value="Image.png"><img style="height: 80px;" class="item lazy" src="Image.png">Image.png</th>
            <th><input type="radio" id="pickimg2" value="Color.png"><img style="height: 80px;" class="item lazy" src="Color.png">Color.png</th>
            <th><input type="radio" id="pickimg3" value="Red.png"><img style="height: 80px;" class="item lazy" src="Red.png">Red.png</th>
    </tbody>
</table>


$('#gallery').DataTable({
    "responsive": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
    searching: true,
    //'bFilter':false,
   // "bSearchable":false,
   // filter: false,
    deferRender: true,
    paging: true,
    cache: true,
    pageLength: 50,
    pagingType: "simple_numbers",
    lengthMenu: [ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 150,200,250],
    "order": [],
    select: {
        style: "multi"
    },
    "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">', // Positions table elements
    language: {
        paginate: {
            previous: "<i class='fas fa-angle-left'>",
            next: "<i class='fas fa-angle-right'>"
        }
    },
    "drawCallback": function(settings) {
    }
});
```

[image]

if i want to search by **varientv1664925416712.png**, Datatable is not working

Comment: Edited title to match the other questions.

Comment: I did not, can do so if you want to be sure it was not me...

Comment: Can you show us how you are actually building your table? The code in the question does not place images in the table, it just places text strings in the table. In other words, a [mre] would help. (Maybe this is the reason for the down-vote, I would guess.)

Comment: updated columns value

Comment: Take a look at [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data). Using this, you can specify one value for the display (the HTML for your button and image), and another value for sorting and filtering (the image file name).  There are lots of questions on Stack Overflow which show more examples of this technique.